# Error: failed to sign JWT, the key is probably invalid

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I am using TG_bot for booking room, an error with google Calendar API problems and just created Google Service Account that generated Json key for access Calendar purpose but when TG_Bot to check my normal gmail account calendar prompted this error

> listBookedEventsByRoom Error: Error: failed to sign JWT, the key is probably invalid
> listEmptySlotsInDay Error: Error: failed to sign JWT, the key is probably invalid

Here is key configuration:

Settings.js file

```
const key = require('../data/tghkbooking-dxxxxxxx.json').private_key;
const SERVICE_ACCT_ID = xxxxx@xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
const CALENDAR_URL = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=xxxxxxxxgmail.com&ctz=Asia%2FHong_Kong';
const CALENDAR_ID={"primary": "xx@gmail.com","th":"xx@gmail.com","ko":xx@gmail.com","kc":"xx@gmail.com","hl":"xx@gmail.com","ml":"xx@gmail.com","fg":"xx@gmail.com","q1":xx@gmail.com","q2":"xx@gmail.com","qc":xx@gmail.com","dr":xx@gmail.com","bb":"xx@gmail.com","tt":"xx@gmail.com","mc":"xx@gmail.com","ak":"xx@gmail.com","sk":"xx@gmail.com","zk":"xx@gmail.com"
};
const TIMEZONE = 'UTC+08:00';

module.exports.calendarUrl = CALENDAR_URL;
module.exports.serviceAcctId = SERVICE_ACCT_ID;
module.exports.calendarId = CALENDAR_ID;
module.exports.key = key;
module.exports.timezone = TIMEZONE;


export { CONFIG as default, ROOM_CONFIG, SESSION_LENGTH, BOOKING_DURATION_OPTIONS };`

.env file

TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxttl_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx SERVICE_ACCT_ID=xxxxx@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com CALENDAR_ID={"primary": "xx@gmail.com","th":"xx@gmail.com","ko":xx@gmail.com","kc":"xx@gmail.com","hl":"xx@gmail.com","ml":"xx@gmail.com","fg":"xx@gmail.com","q1":xx@gmail.com","q2":"xx@gmail.com","qc":xx@gmail.com","dr":xx@gmail.com","bb":"xx@gmail.com","tt":"xx@gmail.com","mc":"xx@gmail.com","ak":"xx@gmail.com","sk":"xx@gmail.com","zk":"xx@gmail.com" }; CALENDAR_URL=https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=xxxxx%40gmail.com&ctz=Asia%2FHong_Kong GOOGLE_KEYFILE_PATH=../data/xxxx-xxxxxx.json
```

Step1:Create service account

step2:create Gmail Normal account

step3:Generated Json Key from Google API service account.

step4: Put TG Token , Service_ACCT_ID , CALENDAR_ID , CALENDAR_URL to settings.js

Here is TG_BOT project
https://github.com/GovTechSG/butler-bo

Comment: welcome to stack please include [example] we need to see your authorization code at very minimum.